# How to add project to the Google Developer Console with the API?

Tags: php, python, dns, google-api, google-cloud-platform

I have couple of projects in the Google Developer Console, and I have just
 enabled the Google Cloud DNS API.

This is what I want to do:

1. Add a project with the API
2. Get the project name
3. Add a zone
4. Get the zone name

I already completed the edit/delete/add actions with the Google Cloud API.

Answer (score 0):

I had wrong approach for this.

I completed this by adding domain name/zone name to project that already exists.
Thank you google.

```
def add_zone(self, domain=None, zone_name=None, project_name='stable-plasma-833'):
    BODY = {
          'name' : zone_name,
          'dnsName' : domain+".",
          'description' : domain+ ' zone'
    }
    try:
        response = self.service.managedZones().create(project=project_name,
                                                   body=BODY
                                                   ).execute()
        print response

    except errors.HttpError, error:
        print 'An error occurred: %s' % error
```